# Streamlining a Select Case

Tags: vba, excel, select, case, excel-2013

I am still rather new to VBA but after a bit of research i have manged to build the below select case.

I would like to hide/unhide the number of rows specified in a cell. I currently have a select case that works but is very long winded and is restricted to only 30.

```
Sub Toggle_Rows()
Dim Sheet As Worksheet: Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calendar")
Change Sheet1 to the name of your sheet

Select Case CStr(Sheet.Range("NoEmployees").Value2)

Case "1"
    Sheet.Rows("8:36").Hidden = True
    Sheet.Rows("7:7").Hidden = False
Case "2"
    Sheet.Rows("9:36").Hidden = True
    Sheet.Rows("7:8").Hidden = False
Case "3"
    Sheet.Rows("10:36").Hidden = True
    Sheet.Rows("7:9").Hidden = False
Case "4"
    Sheet.Rows("11:36").Hidden = True
    Sheet.Rows("7:10").Hidden = False
Case "5"
    Sheet.Rows("12:36").Hidden = True
    Sheet.Rows("7:11").Hidden = False
Case "6"
    Sheet.Rows("13:36").Hidden = True
    Sheet.Rows("7:12").Hidden = False
Case "7"
    Sheet.Rows("14:36").Hidden = True
    Sheet.Rows("7:13").Hidden = False
Case "8"
    Sheet.Rows("15:36").Hidden = True
    Sheet.Rows("7:14").Hidden = False
Case "9"
    Sheet.Rows("16:36").Hidden = True
    Sheet.Rows("7:15").Hidden = False
Case "10"
    Sheet.Rows("17:36").Hidden = True
    Sheet.Rows("7:16").Hidden = False

ETC...

Case Else

End Select

End Sub
```

If somebody could explain a way in which i could shorten this down and also expand the number of rows it will hide/unhide then it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest you only really need something like this

```
Select case CLng(Sheet.Range("NoEmployees").Value2)

Case 1 to 30
    Sheet.Rows("7:36").Hidden = True
    Sheet.Rows(7).resize(CLng(Sheet.Range("NoEmployees").Value2)).Hidden = False
End Select
```

I left the Select Case in there as I assumed you wanted to limit the rows that could be affected.

Comment: beat me to it, too slow on the Kboard :)

Answer (score 4):

In your case your variable and the ranges you want to hide/unhide correlate linear. Therefore you don't need a select case but could just use the following:

```
val = your value
Sheet.Rows(7+val & ":36").Hidden = True
Sheet.Rows("7:" & 6+val).Hidden = False
```

to cover all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use a table, so you just look up your CASE value, and there you find the 2 numbers you need.  If your CASE values are (or can be turned into) successive integers, you could use an array; otherwise some kind of dictionary would do.